# can you group multiple images in a div

Tags: html, css, komodoedit

Example given below

```
 <div id="SocialMediaBadges">

    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/liftedattire">
        <img src="facebook.png"/>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com/liftedattire">
        <img src="twitter.png"/>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.instagram.com/liftedattire">
        <img src="instagram.pdf"/>
    </a>

</div>
```

and then have css align them up with something like this? I've tried the code but unfortunately, it didn't work. I can code them individually but this seemed a lot more efficient.

```
#SocialMediaBadges {
   float:left;
   width:120px;
   height:90px;
   margin:5px; 
}
```

Comment: Use `#SocialMediaBadges a { ... }` to apply the CSS properties to the `a` elements that are descendants of the tag with _id_ `SocialMediaBadges`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#SocialMediaBadges img{
    float:left;
    width:120px;
    height:90px;
    margin:5px; 
}
```

**[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/qR6wP/1/)**

Note: if you want to address an element inside an element you can do it by appending elements in the css rule.

For example `#id_name div p a` will address all the links that are inside a `p` element nested in `div` element that also nested in element with id = id_name

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware that you had to "img" when calling images within a div. Thanks again!!

Comment: i def will in 1 minute, so I am assuming that is the rule when calling all images within a div? Sorry, I am an amateur.

Comment: I added an explanation in my answer.

Comment: omg forgot all about that!! thanks again for the help! keep it up!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#SocialMediaBadges a img{
    float:left;
    width:120px;
    height:90px;
    margin:5px; 
}
```

also you cant put pdf in html  `<img src="instagram.pdf"/>`

Comment: lol, ops!! That's just how the file downloaded from the instagram website, thanks tho!!

Answer (score 0):

img can be nested inside div 
 [the next HTML elements can be nested inside div element](http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/div/html5_div_tag_nested.php)